# Why signed android apk is not running on emulator

Tags: java, android, apk, signing

I have made a signed apk of an android project. Whenever my client try to run it on the emulator, he faces the following error message:

```
D:\Android\android-sdk-
windows\tools>adb install -r abc.apk
500 KB/s (6940708 bytes in 13.534s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/abc.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

What is the resolution?

Comment: Is an unsigned version of your app already installed on the emulator?

Comment: I know you say it's signed, but that error msg sounds like to me it's not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my case it was because I signed it on a machine running JDK 7. Downgrading to JDK 6 fixed the problem. Thanks [java.lang.SecurityException when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161931/java-lang-securityexception-when-install-apk/7114575#7114575) for the suggestion!

Comment: If you're signing yourself with jarsigner and have JDK 7 you can add the options "-digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA" to the jarsigner command and it will work with JDK7.

Comment: How @GregEnnis . can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @AbdulSaleem not really, that answer was 5 years ago. I urge you to switch to Android Studio at this point

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by steelbytes, the error `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` suggests that the APK isn't signed like you think it is.

Run this command to verify which certificate was used to sign the APK:
`jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs abc.apk`

For each entry in the APK, you should see something like this:

```
sm    152412 Wed Oct 14 14:16:52 CEST 2009 classes.dex

      X.509, CN=Meebo, OU=Meebo, O=Meebo, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
      [certificate is valid from 28/10/08 06:49 to 13/08/82 07:49]
```

Otherwise, if the APK isn't signed, you'll get the message `jar is unsigned`.

Answer (score 2):

try below code it's worked for me.

```
Below line run when your jdk version is 6 for singing the apk

H:\Keytool>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_09\bin\jarsigner.exe" -verbose -keystore donate.keystore "H:\Keytool\yourapkName.apk.apk" donate.keystore 

Below line run when your jdk version is 7 for singing the apk

H:\Keytool>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\jarsigner.exe" -verbose -keyst
ore denote.keyStore "H:\Keytool\yourapkName.apk" denote.keyStore -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA
```

Comment: "-digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA" solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

As Dan pointed out, check if you're running JDK 7.  More info:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19567

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Command:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat
```

It will give you a more detail on which exact file is not signed:

```
Package has no certificates at entry assets/META-INF/AIR/application.xml; ignoring!
```

Answer (score -1):

You could check if the client has not disabled installation of unsigned apps in the emulator.

Comment: All apps must be signed; an Android device (or emulator) will not accept an unsigned APK for installation.

Comment: If you're referring to allowing non-Market apps, this setting doesn't apply when "sideloading" via `adb`.

Comment: No I am specifically referring to allowing unsigned application to be allowed to be installed.

Comment: Ok, I haven't seen this setting before. I tried uploading an unsigned APK to a device and to an emultor and both refused it with `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES`. Where would this be configured?

Comment: The setting I am talking of is at Settings->Applications->Unknown Sources

Comment: That's the setting I referred to in my second comment (it allows non-Market apps, not unsigned apps). 
Try it for yourself; loading an unsigned APK onto either a device or emulator with "Unknown Sources" enabled *still* results in the device rejecting the APK.  The PackageParser will say "Package com.example has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml; ignoring!".