# java.lang.SecurityException when install apk

Tags: android

as you know apk is a zip archive, I extracted it and replaced some resources, and zipped it again, when I install it, I get this exception

java.lang.SecurityException: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF has invalid digest

any solution for this error??

Comment: [here](http://asantoso.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/how-to-build-android-application-package-apk-from-the-command-line-using-the-sdk-tools-continuously-integrated-using-cruisecontrol/) is APK build process. It may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you sign it after re-packing it? Changing anything in it broke the existing signature.

If the package is already installed and you re-sign the new one with a different signing key, it will also refuse to install.

Answer (score 26):

I came across this same error caused by having installed the JDK 7 instead of 6.  Hope it helps some other people with this error.

Comment: If you're signing yourself with jarsigner and have JDK 7 you can add the options "-digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA" to the jarsigner command and it will work with JDK7.

Comment: gravitron - Thanks for the informational and helpful comment! This is a better answer since you don't have to downgrade your SDK

Comment: Great comment, gravitron! It helped.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was wrong certificate alias in keystore. I changed it to "CERT" and it started to work.
I used this command:
keytool -changealias -alias "1" -destalias "CERT" -keystore android.jks