# Android update to gradle 3.2.1 [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION] on Android <=6

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-install-apk, apksigner

After updating the gradle tools version from **3.1.4** to **3.2.1** the app cannot be installed anymore on the Android 6.0 and bellow on **release** builds (Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]).

```
compileSdkVersion = 28 
minSdkVersion = 19
targetSdkVersion = 27
gradleToolsVersion = 3.2.1


distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

APK generated by 3.1.4 AndroidManifest attributes:

```
android:versionCode=".."
android:versionName=".."
android:installLocation="1"
package=".."
```

APK generated by 3.2.1 AndroidManifest attributes:

```
android:versionCode=".."
android:versionName=".."
android:installLocation="1"
android:compileSdkVersion="28"
android:compileSdkVersionCodename="9"
package=".."
platformBuildVersionCode="same as versionCode"
platformBuildVersionName="same as versionName"
```

If I downgrade *just* the version of the gradle build tools from **3.2.1** to **3.1.4** then it's working.

Exception:

```
12-24 11:55:40.930 1498-1527/system_process W/PackageManager: Failed collect during installPackageLI
android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed reading resources.arsc in java.util.jar.StrictJarFile@39b13b4e
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.loadCertificates(PackageParser.java:600)
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1094)
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1049)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:10564)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$2300(PackageManagerService.java:234)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$6.run(PackageManagerService.java:8627)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF has invalid digest for resources.arsc in resources.arsc
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.invalidDigest(JarVerifier.java:140)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.access$000(JarVerifier.java:51)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierEntry.verify(JarVerifier.java:132)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarFileInputStream.read(JarFile.java:117)
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.readFullyIgnoringContents(PackageParser.java:5015)
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.loadCertificates(PackageParser.java:597)
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1094) 
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1049) 
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:10564) 
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$2300(PackageManagerService.java:234) 
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$6.run(PackageManagerService.java:8627) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Comment: What are the values of the versionCode and versionName? Are they strings of references to resources? They should be the former.

Comment: versionCode = "4502"
versionName ="4.1-dev4"
For both Apk's

Comment: So hardcoded strings? Do you have other android:xxx attributes in your manifest that would maybe reference a string resource instead of being a hardcoded string?

Comment: Yes, they are strings merged from gradle file. In manifest tag I don't see any references, just in activitiy, broadcastreceiver, application(icon, classes, theme, etc). But I took a look on diffs between Manifests (apk analyzer), and I don't see major changes just the different references for activities classes, application icon, themes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Maybe check the logcat of the device, just before the error is thrown, that may give additional clues.

Comment: How big is the resources.arsc in the APK? I have maybe an idea of a bug it could be, depending on the answer.

Comment: The resources.arsc has 24.3 MB (without proguard anh shrinking, I disabled them in order to have faster builds

Comment: A bug which could be related was accidentally introduced in Android Gradle plugin 3.3.0-alpha01 (Canary 1), and fixed in 3.3.0-rc01. Can you try to use the latest version and see if that fixes it?

Comment: Thank you Pierre, updating to the 3.3.0-rc01 works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.SecurityException when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161931/java-lang-securityexception-when-install-apk)

Comment: besides, on Android `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` can be excluded from the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is updating the gradle tools version to 3.3.0-rc1 as [Pierre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265103/pierre) suggested in comments.