# Installing apk problem in android

Tags: android, shell, 3d, command

I'm using Samsung Galaxy POP. Android version 2.2 Froyo. I'm new to android programming. I was too much exited to install Mid3D demo on my phone and see it before I think ahead with it.

the link is here
http://code.google.com/p/min3d/downloads/detail?name=min3dSampleProject1_020.apk&can=2&q=

but when ever I use this

```
>adb install [Mid3D apk file name]
```

an error occurs like :

```
1052 KB/s (1688402 bytes in 1.566s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/min3dSampleProject1_020.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

I'm using Windows 7.

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That APK is indeed not signed. You need to sign it to be able to install it, or just get the sample project source and build it with Eclipse. That will automatically generate a test certificate and sign the APK, so you can try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try google? I found lots of posts when searching for "Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]". It's probably because that APK is not signed. Some phones restrict the installation of foreign, unsigned APK's.

I think there is a setting to allow non-Market apks in  Menu > Settings > Applications > Unknown Sources.

[Here](http://androidforums.com/droid-all-things-root/102685-install_parse_failed_no_certificates-error-message.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551249/why-signed-android-apk-is-not-running-on-emulator), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/android-what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error) are some links from Google after a search.

Comment: I checked the unknown source. But seems to have the same problem

Comment: 'Unknown Sources' is not related to this. You can install with adb regardless of this setting (as long as USB debugging is on, of course). In the context of this setting 'foreign' means 'not from the Android Market', not 'unsigned'. All apks have to be signed to install.

Comment: Apparently the package isn't signed at all, which was allowed for versions of Android <= 1.5. You may want to download the sources and recompile the package yourself, or see if you really need it on Froyo.